# How to validate checkbox in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js and knockout.validation plugins. I am trying to validation the checkbox, if it is checked than its valid otherwise invalid. SO for this i created a custom valdation attribute in knockout :

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/axuyid/8/edit)

```
ko.validation.rule['checked'] = {
    validator: function (value) {
        if (!value) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

And my view model is :

```
function VM()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Approve = ko.observable(false).extend({
        checked: { message: 'Approval required' }
    });
    self.Errors = ko.validation.group(self);
    self.Validate = function(){
        if(self.Errors().length > 0)
        self.Errors.showAllMessages();
    };
}
```

But the validation is not working. Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few problems with your current approach:

1. You have miss typed the `ko.validation.rule` it should be `ko.validation.rules`
2. The custom rule definition and the calling of the `ko.validation.registerExtenders();` should be done before you first try to use the custom validator.
3. In order the validation displayed you need to bind it somewhere with `validationMessage` binding:

   ```
   <span data-bind='validationMessage: Approve'></span>
   ```

So the fixed script:

```
ko.validation.rules['checked'] = {
    validator: function (value) {
      console.log(value);
        if (!value) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

ko.validation.registerExtenders();

function VM()
{
  var self = this;  
  self.Approve = ko.observable(false).extend({
    checked: { message: 'Approval required' }
  });

  self.Errors = ko.validation.group(self);

  self.Validate = function(){    
     if(self.Errors().length > 0)
       self.Errors.showAllMessages();
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

And the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Approve" />  
<span data-bind='validationMessage: Approve'></span>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: Validate">Submit</button>
```

You can try it out here: [Demo](http://jsbin.com/olosuk/1/edit).

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the equal native validator:

```
self.Approve = ko.observable(false).extend({
    equal: { params: true, message: 'check must be ticked' }
  });
```